# AWSApplication load balancer - custom headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-alb

I have question regarding AWS ALB. Does anybody knows if it is possible to modify (specifically ADD) custom headers to requests? Something like proxy_set_header in nginx http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

Comment: Did you find anything helpful about how to add custom headers to requests coming from ALB? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALB and ELB set some standard headers: `X-Forwarded-For:`, `X-Forwarded-Proto:` and `X-Forwarded-Port:` (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html)).

I don't think you can set your own headers. What do you need it for?

Comment: To give a `Retry-After` instruction to the clients in case of error